# Sum total value from hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that shows production quantities of parts that we make.  The production process allows us to 'split' production mid-stream. I am looking for a way to simplify getting the total quantity from all related production records.

Relevant table:

```
ID     Parent ID     Qty    Batch
---------------------------------
1       Null         100     1
2       1             50     1-A
3       1             50     1-B
4       2             50     1-AA
5       Null          40     2
```

The query results that I'd like would grab the total related qty for all children of the top level parent, and sum up

```
ID        Related Qty  TopLevelBatch
-----------------------------------
1         250               1
2         250               1
3         250               1
4         250               1
5          40               2
```

Essentially, I am looking for two things

1. Get the top level ID for each ID, and
2. Get all of the children of a top level ID.

Comment: 1) What have you tried and what isn't working? 2) Will you have multiple levels to your hierarchy or just the one parent and one child?

Comment: I've been relatively stumped on this -- I can get the direct parent, but haven't come up with a way to traverse up and down the ID tree.

Comment: hierarchy can have multiple levels -- parents can branch to multiple children and this can happen at any level.

Comment: 1, 2, 3 and 4 all relate back to batch 1.  So the related rows have 250.  -- I'll add in batch names to make this more clear.

Comment: Ah, if you have a batch name that relates them all to the top level that will completely change the approach to the solution.  Or is that not part of the data?  (Sorry, I deleted my earlier comment because I noticed after I commented that 4 was a child of 2)

Comment: batch numbers can change (engineering change orders)  and aren't something I rely on.  They generally indicate parentage, but are not definitive.

Comment: Is the leading digit part of the batch number static by chance?  It's a much, much simpler query if that column can be used.  At that point it's a simple GROUP BY.

Comment: the leading digit can change based on some engineering requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

… recursive common table expression …

```
create table [relevant table] (id int,parentid int, qty int, batch varchar(10));

insert into [relevant table] 
values
(1, Null, 100, '1'),
(2, 1, 50, '1-A'),
(3, 1, 50, '1-B'),
(4, 2, 50, '1-AA'),
(5, Null, 40, '2');


with cte
as
(
select *, id as topmostparentId, dense_rank() over(order by id) as topparentordinal
from [relevant table] 
where parentid is null
union all
select r.*, c.topmostparentId, c.topparentordinal
from [relevant table] as r
join cte as c on r.parentid = c.id
)
select *, 
    sum(qty) over(partition by topmostparentId) as relatedqty
    -- dense_rank() over(order by topmostparentId) as topparentordinal
from cte
--option(maxrecursion 0)
```